Set Firebase Web Frameworks SSR Database URL?
I'm using Firebase web frameworks.
At a high level, I want to use my firebase-hosted development database for the generated function that does server-side rendering of the page (function ssrhostingname). Right now, I can only get it to use the default database, which is production.
More concretely, I have two realtime databases on my project, project-name.firebaseio.com and project-name-dev1.firebaseio.com.
I have no problem setting the database to development version on the frontend, or on my own cloud functions, but on the generated function that does server-side-rendering, ssrprojectname, I'm always defaulting to project-name.firebaseio.com (prod), when I want to be able to set it to use project-name-dev1.firebaseio.com.
emulator not good enough
I can get it to use the emulator database if I start the realtime database emulator, but that doesn't totally work for me because my DB is big and emulator bugs out when trying to upload my database content to it.
Hints
I see a .env file generated when I start the hosting,function emulators (.firebase/hosting-name/functions/.env). I'm pretty sure this is what the generated ssrhostingname function is using to determine the database:
...
__FIREBASE_DEFAULTS__="config":{"projectId":"project-name", ... 
   databaseURL":"https://project-name.firebaseio.com","storageBucket"...

I'm seeing this on the console when starting up:
[apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/-/webApps/1:REDACTED_NUMBER:web:REDACTED_HASH/config{"projectId":...,"appId":...,"databaseURL":"https://project-name.firebaseio.com","storageBucket"...

and
[apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-name/adminSdkConfig {"projectId":"project-name","databaseURL":"https://project-name.firebaseio.com","storageBucket"...}


The important parts above is that it's listing project-name.firebaseio.com as the database even though I want to use project-name-dev1.firebaseio.com for the database, and not the production version.
config
.firebaserc
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project-name"
  },
  "targets": {
    "project-name": {
      "hosting": {
        "hosting-name": [
          "hosting-name"
        ]
      },
      "database": {
        "main": [
          "project-name",
          "project-name-dev1"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {}
}

I'm using Nuxt / VueFire, Vue 3, but I don't think that matters here.
final thought
Maybe the actual question is, how is that .firebase/project-name/functions/.env generated, and can I control it so that __FIREBASE_DEFAULTS__ has the database I want to use?
